# Can we rename the file name in Jmeter during run time which will be uploaded in the script

Tags: jmeter

I have to upload audio files in the Jmeter script which is stored in my system. E.g. abc.wav is the file store in the system. But in the script the file name format should be "Testinstanceid__itemid__ interactionid.wav". Here "Testinstanceid" is the dynamic value which we can get from correlation of previous response.
But how I can upload the file with this dynamic value during run time and it will upload correctly in the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your `abc.wav` file to the `Testinstanceid__itemid__ interactionid.wav` file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy script like:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(new File('abc.wav'), new File(vars.get('Testinstanceid') + '__itemid__ interactionid.wav'))
```

once you finish the uploading you can delete the file to free up your drive in [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) like:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(vars.get('Testinstanceid') + '__itemid__ interactionid.wav'))
```

where [`vars` stands for JMeterVariables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) class instance, check out the [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) for all available functions